# Android Device Monitor vs Android Monitors ? Whats the difference ? Which one is newer?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-sdk-tools, android-device-monitor

There are two profiling options in Android studio. One is Android Monitors and the second one is Android Device Monitor. I can't find any documentation which describes about their similarities and differences. They do report different results as I tested them. Any ideas ?

**Update:** 
I came across this link where it says that Android Monitors are intended to be a replacement for traceview in Android Device Monitor.
http://tools.android.com/tips/traceview

However, I am still not sure how mature the Android Monitors are compared to Android Device Monitor and what are the changes or improvements made in it.

Comment: Android Device Monitor is an old tool. Android Studio still links to it, as not every feature of the Android Device Monitor has been implemented natively in Android Studio. Eventually, I expect the Android Device Monitor to be retired.

Comment: @CommonsWare So can we assume that Android monitors (cpu and memory monitor etc) is the newer version and should be used ?

Comment: Everything in Android Studio is newer than its equivalent in the Android Device Monitor.

Comment: @CommonsWare okay thanks. The reason I asked is that Android Device Monitor has the new sampling based (for cpu profiling) option which Android monitor doesn't have.